# Transitioning Strip Cork to Tile

Tags: flooring, floor

I haven't come across any instructions on how to install a transitioning strip on cork and additionally in the awkward no-gap/multi-height situation this floor is in with the silicone and all. As a complete novice, could anyone give some pointers as to what to do? I was also debating if just a simple adhesive strip (/reducer molding) would work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the cork your finished surface?

Answer (score 1):

The cork is not meant to be the finished floor. That is why you haven't found any instructions on transitioning.

The corks will wear quickly and start to crumble. It is also porous and will quickly absorb any liquids.

Cork as you have is meant as an underlayment.  I suggest you choose a proper finish flooring to go over it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be similar to any carpet-to-tile transition (no endorsement suggested):

https://www.bliffertlumber.com/shop/building-materials/flooring-materials/floor-trim-and-transitions/carpet-trim/140985-m-d-spice-fluted-2-in-x-36-in-aluminum-carpet-trim?SKU=278715

[image: carpet edge metal strip]

This can be screwed or nailed on the edge of the cork and cover the joint. Screws or nails are often provided with the strip. Predrilling for the screws is probably a good idea, as they're usually small screws.

Other possibilities could be had by web-searching "carpet to tile transition strip" or "carpet edge trim".

Answer (score 0):

Given it's apparently already installed, I'd probably sand a taper into the cork the thickness of the doorframe, going from full thickness on the cork side to essentially none (level with the tile) on the tile side, based on the picture. Caulk or grout the joint.

Or, cut out the cork in the doorframe and install a threshold.